# Cannot Add two filters in CALCULATE function

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am stuck at this Power BI DAX function.
Here is the DAX function:

```
#Count_Computer_with_XYZ_Software = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            ABC_Computer(
            CONTAINS(
                HealthStatus,
                HealthStatus[ComputerName],
                ABC_Computer[ComputerName]
            )),
            FILTER(
                   ABC_Computer,
                   LEFT(ABC_Computer[OS],10) = "Windows 10"
 )
)
```

The logic is:

In first filter, I count rows from ABC_Computers which are common in HealthStatus. Second filter is to check for rows where the row string for OS column starts with "Windows 10". For some reason I am not able to add the second filter in the DAX query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just have some syntax issues. Should be:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            ABC_Computer,
            CONTAINS (
                HealthStatus,
                HealthStatus[ComputerName], ABC_Computer[ComputerName]
            )
        )
    ),
    FILTER ( ABC_Computer, LEFT ( ABC_Computer[OS], 10 ) = "Windows 10" )
)
```

which could also be abbreviated to:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            ABC_Computer,
            CONTAINS (
                HealthStatus,
                HealthStatus[ComputerName], ABC_Computer[ComputerName]
            )
                && LEFT ( ABC_Computer[OS], 10 ) = "Windows 10"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Jeez, I actually tried it after each ")" just be sure. Guess I have to recheck it. Thanks though!